# Adding META keywords and description on Home Page only

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I would like to enter keywords and a description of the home page only of my ruby website.
The home page has 2 files  :

```
1- main_controller
2- home_page.html.erb


<% content_for :html_title, 'Erratum HUmanum Est' %>
<div class="clear"></div>
<div id="video">
  <div class="container">
        <div class="video-glow">
          <h1><%= t('application.home_page.heading')%></h1>
            <div class="clear"></div>
            <div class="video-section">
                <iframe width="418" height="235" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/sfsfsfsfsfsfQ?rel=0;hd=1" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

how can I enter the meta description and keywords on these pages? (I do not want to enter any new ruby gem for this)
Thanks,
Roman

Answer (score 9):

In your `application.html.erb` add something like this;

```
<meta name="description" content="<%= yield(:description) %>" />
<meta name="keywords" content="<%= yield(:keywords) %>" />
```

Then in `home_page.html.erb` add something like this;

```
<%= provide(:description, 'I would like to enter keywords and a description of the home page only of my ruby website. The home page has ') %>  
<%= provide(:keywords, 'Home, fred, grace, heaven, george') %>
```

When you do not pass anything, it will remain empty with no meta_tags.

Comment: many thanks. Do you confirm this will only impact the home page and not the other pages of the website?

Comment: It only shows up where you provide the data. If it works for you, then mark it as the answer.